# Get long timestamp from date picker onDateSet

Tags: android, datepicker, timestamp

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
        int dayOfMonth) {

    dateET.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + monthOfYear + "/" + year);
}
```

I want to avoid user setting date past to current date.

So, is there a way i can get the long timestamp (may be 12:00 A.M of the date set), so that i can compare it with the current timestamp and if it is less, the date will be set to default(current date + 3 days).

Thank You

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have to do it yourself:

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

Comment: And if you want it in seconds you can use TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(msTimestamp);